# Is it possible to write a J program that uses monadic or dyadic forms of verbs based on execution-time values?

Tags: j

It's cool that `3 * 4` results in `12`, and `* 4` results in `1`, but does using the same primitive for both operations ever provide a benefit? For example, let's say I were to define the following:

```
SIGNUM =: * : [:
TIMES =: [: : *
```

If I were to only ever use `SIGNUM` and `TIMES` instead of `*`, would I ever miss out on a clever use of `*`? That is, `x TIMES y` seems to be exactly the same as `x * y` for every `x` I can imagine (although my imagination is pretty limited in this regard). Is there an `x` where `x * y` produces the same result as `SIGNUM y`?

In case `* : [:` isn't immediately clear, the following should illustrate:

```
   SIGNUM =: * : [:
   TIMES =: [: : *
   SIGNUM 4
1
   3 TIMES 4
12
   * 4
1
   3 * 4
12
   3 SIGNUM 4
|domain error: SIGNUM
|   3     SIGNUM 4
   TIMES 4
|domain error: TIMES
|       TIMES 4
```

Comment: `TIMES` is a forced dyadic `*` so when `*` is dyadic it's completely equivalent to `TIMES`.

Comment: Right, @Eelvex. So, would I lose any programmatic benefit if I always used `TIMES` instead of dyadic `*`? I'm thinking not. If not, doesn't having the same verb have both a dyadic and monadic meaning just introduce confusion?

Comment: I'm asking, because so far I've found the decisions behind J to be wise. I'm assuming there is wisdom behind giving verbs both monadic and dyadic meanings, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: I don't think you'ld lose any programmatic benefit. I suppose having monadic/dyadic versions could be confusing. There are a lot of primitives that have completely unrelated monadic/dyadic meaning (like `<`, `+`, etc).

Comment: IMO you don't lose functionality by using `TIMES` and `SIGNUM`, you only gain clarity. Giving primitives monadic and dyadic meanings is simply character economy. When J was being designed as "the next APL", the idea was that J should use only ASCII characters for primitives (single characters first, then variations with `.` and `:`). You only have so many of those available.

Comment: When you rename primitives to mnemonics you do run the risk of not having the interpreter recognize the opportunities for special code. This is pointed out most clearly in Henry Rich's book J for C Programmers in chapter 41. http://www.jsoftware.com/help/jforc/readable_tacit_definitions.htm#_Toc191734593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write conclusions from the comments down:

There is no direct language-level reason not to use names for primitives

Using names instead of primitives *can* however harm performance, as [special code](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Vocabulary/SpecialCombinations) does not necessarily get triggered. I think this can be remedied by fixing verbs after building them with `f.`.

The reason for having the same name for monadic and dyadic verbs is historical: APL used it before. Most verbs have a related actions in monadic / dyadic versions and inflections (a number of trailing dots and colons).

For instance, `^` can be expressed in traditional notation as `pow(x,y)` or `exp(y)`  where x and y are left and right arguments, and e is Euler's constant. Here, the monadic version is the same as the dyadic version, with a sensible default left argument. Different inflections of the same root are all power-related verbs: 
 - `^.` does logarithms (base e for the monad)
 - `^:` does Power conjunction, applying a verb a variable number of times.

Other relations between monadic and dyadic verbs can also exist, for example `$` can be said to get or set the Shape of an array, depending on whether it is used as monad or dyad.

That said, I think that once one gets a bit of experience with J, it becomes easier to spot which valence a verb has based on the sentence it is used in. Examples are:

```
Monad @ Ambiv NB. Mv is always used monadically, Av depends on arguments
Ambiv & Monad
(Dyad Monad) NB. A hook, where verb 1 is always dyadic
(Ambiv Dyad Ambiv) NB. A fork, the middle is one always dyadic
```

Comment: When you rename primitives to mnemonics you do run the risk of not having the interpreter recognize the opportunities for special code. This is pointed out most clearly in Henry Rich's book J for C Programmers in chapter 41. http://www.jsoftware.com/help/jforc/readable_tacit_definitions.htm#_Toc191734593

Comment: That's also in my answer, third sentence. Thanks for the link though :).

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I guess I got thrown with the first observation that there were no reasons, but I think now that you may be drawing a distinction between the language in theory and the language as implemented. With J being so interactive those two domains feel closer than they are for many other languages.

Answer (score 1):

It was probably a mistake to use the same symbols for dyadic and monadic built-ins except for those where the monadic case is a default parameter to the dyad.

TIMES =: 1&$: : *

would be a good defnition that doesn't give an error.

As for ambivalent cases,

(3 * TIMES) 4
12
  2 (3 * TIMES) 4
24

Another useful ambivalent verb is:

TIMESORSQUARE =: *~

*~ 3
9
  2 *~ 3
6